# can't override django Form widget attributes correctly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to change the name of the widget but then i have two names inside the input

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # to delete colon after field's name
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        name = "document"
        fields = ('id',
                  'comment',
                  'private',
                  'position',
                  'marked')
        # fields = '__all__'

    marked = forms.IntegerField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
            attrs={
                'name': "asdasdjasdasjdldsa",
                'id': "device_documents___name___marked",
                'class': 'check preview_image',
                'onchange': 'cbChange(this)',
                'mazen': "document_set-__name__-position"
            },
        )
    )
```

but if i print this i have two name **name="marked"** and **name="asdasdjasdasjdldsa"** how to delete the first one?

```
print(f["marked"])
<input type="number" name="marked" name="asdasdjasdasjdldsa" id="device_documents___name___marked" class="check preview_image" onchange="cbChange(this)" mazen="document_set-__name__-position">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django needs the name of the field to match the class definition. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible to process the submitted form data. Your only way of changing the widget's name attribute is to change the form field definition.

You didn't say *why* you want the name attribute to change. If you really wanted to hack it. You could create a custom widget with a template that uses the desired name.